# Spring TypeConverter fails on Camel RouteBuilder subclass

Tags: spring, apache-camel, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

In an attempt to install my component on karaf I get the following error: 
`Caused by: org.apache.camel.CamelException: Cannot find any routes with this RouteBuilder reference: RouteBuilderRef[logparserRouteBean]`

I've narrowed it down to a conversion error in AbstractBeanFactory using the SimpleTypeConverter as returned by the `getTypeConverter()`. [image]

[image]

Given that PerformanceLogRoute extends org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder, how can the convertion fail??

Suggestions, and ideas to any solution is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

```
package no.osl.cdms.profile.routes;

import no.osl.cdms.profile.api.TimeMeasurement;
import no.osl.cdms.profile.factories.EntityFactory;
import no.osl.cdms.profile.log.TimeMeasurementEntity;
import no.osl.cdms.profile.parser.LogLineRegexParser;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

import java.util.Map;

public class PerformanceLogRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    public static final String PERFORMANCE_LOG_ROUTE_ID = "PerformanceLogRoute";
    private static final String LOG_DIRECTORY = "C:/data";
    private static final String LOG_FILE = "performance.log";
    private static final int DELAY = 0;

    private LogLineRegexParser logLineRegexParser = new LogLineRegexParser();
    private EntityFactory entityFactory = EntityFactory.getInstance();

    private static final String LOG_FILE_ENDPOINT = "stream:file?    fileName="+LOG_DIRECTORY +"/"+LOG_FILE+"&scanStream=true&scanStreamDelay=" + DELAY;
    private static final String DATABASE_ENDPOINT = "jpa:";


    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception{
        fromF(LOG_FILE_ENDPOINT, LOG_DIRECTORY, LOG_FILE, DELAY)
            .convertBodyTo(String.class)                  // Converts input to String
            .choice().when(body().isGreaterThan(""))      // Ignores empty lines
            .bean(logLineRegexParser, "parse")            // Parses log entry into String map
            .bean(entityFactory, "createTimemeasurement") // Parses log entry into database format
            .split(body())
            .choice().when(body().isNotNull())
            .toF(DATABASE_ENDPOINT, body().getClass().toString())
            .routeId(PERFORMANCE_LOG_ROUTE_ID);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return PERFORMANCE_LOG_ROUTE_ID;
    }
}
```

The xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <bean id="logparserRouteBean" class="no.osl.cdms.profile.routes.PerformanceLogRoute" />
<camelContext id="cdms-core-camel-context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <routeBuilder ref="logparserRouteBean" />
</camelContext>

</beans>
```

This is what I found at this moment. From what I remember it is identical to what caused the error, but I'll double check in the morning.

Comment: Hi, could you post your code too please?

Comment: The routing class or the camel xml?

Comment: Everything please, that would help greatly :)

Comment: I'll see what I can get my hands on from this computer. :)

Comment: Try with another route builder that is very simple and dont have code that initializes etc just a simple camel route in the configure method.

Comment: And does it work from an unit test / eg plain java. As you have tagged this with Karaf / SMX you may run in OSGi and then shit can happend

Comment: @ClausIbsen  I changed the route to `fromF(LOG_FILE_ENDPOINT).bean(this, "print");` and added a print method to the class. Still got the same error when deploying to karaf.  The unit tests also work, and is done by extending `CamelSpringTestSupport`

Comment: Could this an issue related to dependency versions on the osgi container? I've tried a simple test of the SimpleTypeConverter and everything seems to work fine during test. So is it possible that there are several 'different' versions of RouteBuilder in play here?